# How to uninstall the exe file running in windows client from puppet manifest

Tags: windows, puppet

How can I uninstall an .exe file running on a Windows client with puppet?

ie.

```
package { "WinRAR":
  ensure => absent,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @ferventcoder's answer, the [latest version of winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) is called:

"WinRAR 5.21 beta 2 (64-bit)"

So this would uninstall it:

```
package { 'WinRAR 5.21 beta 2 (64-bit)':
  ensure => absent,
  uninstall_options => ['/S'], #stops the prompt from coming up
}
```

An example of it in action:

[image: How it works]

Answer (score 1):

You should review the official documentation, which is very helpful in this aspect.

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/resources_package_windows.html
and https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/resources_package_windows.html#package-name-must-be-the-displayname

From the above, it will mention that with packages you need to see what the ARP (Add/Remove Programs) `DisplayName` name is being reported as for Puppet. A simple

```
puppet resource package
```

Should help you get the proper name that you need to add to the title (it's likely not just WinRAR).